# Implicit conversion from UnsafeBufferPointer to UnsafeRawBufferPointer

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers

`UnsafePointer` [can be implicitly cast](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsaferawpointer#overview) to `UnsafeRawPointers` when passed as parameters:

```
var x = 42

func print<T>(address p: UnsafeRawPointer, as type: T.Type) {
    print(p.load(as: type))
}

withUnsafePointer(to: &x) { (ptr) in
    print(address: ptr, as: Int.self)  // Prints "42"
}
```

However, it seems that `UnsafeBufferPointer` cannot be implicitly cast to `UnsafeRawBufferPointer`:

```
var x = 42

func printBuffer<T>(address p: UnsafeRawBufferPointer, as type: T.Type) {
    print(p.load(as: type))
}

withUnsafePointer(to: &x) { (ptr) in
    let buff = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: ptr, count: 1)
    printBuffer(address: buff, as: Int.self)  // 1
}
```

In this snippet, the line marked `// 1` errors:

> cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeBufferPointer' to expected argument type 'UnsafeRawBufferPointer'

Why is this implicit conversion not possible, when the previous one is allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot *cast* a `UnsafeBufferPointer` to a `UnsafeRawBufferPointer`
because that is more than reinterpreting the pointer: It requires
to *calculate* the raw byte count.

But you can *create* a `UnsafeRawBufferPointer` from a `UnsafeBufferPointer`:

```
withUnsafePointer(to: &x) { (ptr) in
    let buff = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: ptr, count: 1)
    let rawBuff = UnsafeRawBufferPointer.init(buff)
    printBuffer(address: rawBuff, as: Int.self)
}
```

Here is the implementation of that initializer in [UnsafeRawBufferPointer.swift.gyb](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/UnsafeRawBufferPointer.swift.gyb#L329):

```
  /// Creates a raw buffer over the contiguous bytes in the given typed buffer.
  ///
  /// - Parameter buffer: The typed buffer to convert to a raw buffer. The
  ///   buffer's type `T` must be a trivial type.
  @_inlineable
  public init<T>(_ buffer: UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<T>) {
    self.init(start: buffer.baseAddress!,
      count: buffer.count * MemoryLayout<T>.stride)
  }
```